# Trying to aggregate quantities across multiple tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a stock synch which compares product quantities from three different tables:
EWM
USOR
DSOR

The maths behind the stock synch is  EWM - (USOR + DSOR) = Misalignment
The EWM table divides the product quantities by the different storage types that products are held in which necessitates the need to have the quantities aggregated before being used in the end query but I keep getting the wrong figure after aggregating the quantities so I think I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to spot it.

Here's my code:

```
--Table for EWM Data--
create table EWM(
Date_loaded date,
Sap_code bigint, 
Product_description varchar(100),
Location nvarchar(50),
Storage_type varchar(50),
Quantity int,
Sap_batch nvarchar(50),
Expiry_date date,
Stock_type varchar(50)
);

--Table for USOR Data--
create table USOR(
Date_Loaded date,
Sap_Code bigint,
Product_description varchar(100),
Pack nvarchar(50),
Cost_price decimal,
Trade_price decimal,
Stock int,
Location nvarchar(50),
);

--Table for DSOR--
create table DSOR(
Date_Loaded datetime,
Sap_code bigint,
Product_description varchar(100),
Bin_location nvarchar(50),
Location varchar(50),
Pack nvarchar(50),
Units int,
Total int,
);
 
--Table for difference between EWM and USOR+DSOR--
create table Misalignment
(
Date_loaded date,
Sap_code bigint,
Product_description varchar(100),
Pack nvarchar(50),
Location nvarchar(50),
Total_difference int
) 
 --Inserting data in Misalingment using query from USOR, USOR_DSOR, EWM --
 WITH x AS (
    SELECT SAP_Code, Quantity 
    FROM EWM 
    GROUP BY SAP_Code, Quantity
)
insert into Misalignment(Date_Loaded, Sap_code, Product_description, Location, Total_difference)
 Select USOR.Date_Loaded, USOR.Sap_Code, USOR.Product_description,  USOR.Location, sum(x.Quantity - (USOR.stock  + DSOR.Total))as Total_difference 

FROM x 
 INNER JOIN USOR ON x.SAP_Code = USOR.SAP_Code
 INNER JOIN DSOR ON x.SAP_Code = DSOR.SAP_Code
 group by USOR.Date_Loaded, USOR.Sap_Code, USOR.Product_description, USOR.Pack, USOR.Location

 select * from Misalignment
 where Total_difference > 0
 order by Total_difference
 desc
```

I ran the query below to test my code out:

```
 select * from ewm
 where  Date_loaded = '2020-10-05' and Sap_code = 1002945
 select * from DSOR
 where Sap_code = 1002945  and Date_loaded= '2020-10-05'
 select * from Misalignment
 where Sap_code  = 1002945 and Date_loaded = '2020-10-05'
```

This was the result: 
[image]

The actual result should be 0.
Any suggestions?

Comment: WIthout sample data that's someone hard to give a definition opinion on. The reason, however, is "simple"; because that's what the expression evaluated to.

Comment: Hi - you are missing the data from USOR in your example. Also, please can you provide the data for all 3 source tables as INSERT statements rather than pictures? Thanks

Comment: @NickW, Thank you for pointing out that I forgot to include the USOR. Didn't catch that. Apologies still very new to SQL, can you clarify what you mean by provide data for source tables as insert statements? Do you mean the files I'm loading for each table?

Comment: Hi - if you can provide data that is in a format that it easy for someone to load into a table (rather than having to manually key) then it is more likely that they will create their own version of your tables and try out some solutions.
In SQL Server, right-click on the DB, Tasks>Generate Scripts. Select the relevant tables and then click the "Advanced" button. There is an option "Types of data to script" so select a value that include data